# Blueprint HTML Columns Question

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

So looking into [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), the default width is 950px and using 24 columns. My question is why  change the columns to either lower or higher? We are still in the end getting 950px total.

Do people do this for more control over the columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the column width you get finer control over spacing, or the opposite where you would get less control over spacing in the 950px grid. Yes, in the end you still get 950px width total space to work with.